# Finding non-trivial fixed points of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Based on my notes I know the following if matrix A has a nontrivial fixed point, then $det(I-A) = 0$.

Suppose I have a matrix A such that Row 1 is [1 0] and Row 2 is [1 0] (apologies for the notation).

I know this matrix has a non trivial fixed point based on the calculation of $det(I-A)$ being equal to 0.

But, how do I the find the fixed point(s)?

Recall:
Solutions to the matrix equation $Ax = x$, if any, are called fixed points of A.

Comment: Yes, that's correct A11 is 1 A12 is 0 A21 is 1 and A22 is 0.

Comment: I'm looking for non trivial fixed points of the Matrix A (I tagged it as Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors, since this question is from that particular section).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The things you called fixed points are called eigenvectors with eigenvalue $1$.

In this particular case do note that if $x=\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}$ then $Ax=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_1 \end{pmatrix}$ so the vectors of the form $\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_1 \end{pmatrix}$ are "fixed points" in this particular case.

In the general case to find the fixed points you want to find a basis of $Ker(I-A)$ and the span of that basis is the set of "fixed points".

Comment: Are non trivial fixed points always an Eigenvector with values of 1? This is what the answer corresponds to. The answer indicates x = t * a column vector with 2 rows of 1 for this particular case.

Comment: If a non trivial fixed point is every $x$ such that $Ax=x$ then yes they are always eigenvectors with eigenvalue $1$. And yes, you say the answers are of the form $t \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and I say they are fo the form $\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_1 \end{pmatrix}$ both answers are equivalent.

Comment: Much appreciated and thank you.